# Get index in raster of tile layer point

Tags: python, leaflet, raster, gdal, geotiff

I have a large raster encoded as a cloud optimized geoTIFF (coordinate system EPSG:4326), which i am drawing on a Leaflet map as a TileLayer (i use tiling for performance reasons). The tiles are served via a Terracotta server,

```
https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/terracotta
```

When the map is clicked, a click event containing (lat,lon,zoom) is emitted. Now my question is,

**How do i determine the index (i,j) of the pixel in the raster corresponding to the click event?**

As a first try, i located the nearest point in the raster array to the (lat, lon) of the click event. However, the index was only correct within +/- 1 along each axis. As i understand, the discrepancy is due to the fact that the tiles are rendered in a different coordinate projection (EPSG:3857) in the Leaflet map.

Next, i took a dive into the Terracotta source code, from which i learned how to translate (lat,lon,zoom) into tile indices (x,y,z where z is zoom) [1]. I also located where the data is read from the raster [2], but it remains unclear to me how to do the full mapping into the index of the pixel in the original raster. Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

[1] [https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile/blob/master/mercantile/**init**.py#L285](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile/blob/master/mercantile/__init__.py#L285)

[2] https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/terracotta/blob/master/terracotta/drivers/raster_base.py#L451

Comment: Does `layerPointToLatLng()` help? https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-layerpointtolatlng

Comment: The mapping ```layerPointToLatLng()``` (and the reverse ```latLngToLayerPoint()```) maps between (lat,lon) and pixels drawn on the map canvas - not the pixels in the original raster. Hence some kind of additional mapping would be needed.